# Jquery & HTML - dynamically create div-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Say I have a textfield where the dimensions of the table are given. like 2 3

now I need to write a function that creates a table out of div-tags with those dimensions. The table has to be inserted in the `<div id="output">` -element

I was thinking of making a string with osme for-loops that looks like this

```
<div> 
<div> </div>
<div> </div>
</div>
<div> 
... (more columns)
</div>
```

So that looks like a sequence of div-tags and afterwards I would convert this to html and insert it.

But isn't there a more efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

In your Javascript,

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

 var rows,cols,str="";
 function generateTable()
 {
 rows = documnt.getElementById('rows').value;
 cols = documnt.getElementById('cols').value;
 str ="<table>"
 for(var i=0;i<rows;i++)
 {
 str = str+"<tr>";
 for(vat j=0;j<cols;j++)
 {
 str = str+"<td></td>";
 }
 str =str+"</tr>";
 }
 str = str + "</table>;

 documnt.getElementById('output').innerHTML = str;
 }

  </script>
```

In your HTML,

```
   <input type="number" id="rows" placeholder="Number of rows" />
   <input type="number" id="cols" placeholder="Number of cols" />
   <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit" onClick="generateTable();" />

   <br>
   <br>
   <div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```js
var rows = 3; //these would be populated by your text field entries
var columns = 2;

function makeTable() {
  html = '<table>';
  
  for(var i=0; i<rows; i++) {      
    html += '<tr>';      
    
    for(var j=0; j<columns; j++) {
      html += '<td><p>Some Data</p></td>';
    }
    
    html += '</tr>';
  }
 
  html += '</table>';
  
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = html;
}
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html> 
  <head>  
   <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
   <title>Table Maker</title>
  </head>
  <body> 
   <div id="output" onClick="makeTable()"><h1>Click me to make a table!</h1></div>   
  </body>
 </html>
```